# docker compose build single container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using Compose, if I run `docker-compose build`, it will rebuild **all** the containers :

```
> docker-compose build
Building elasticsearch
Step 1 : FROM elasticsearch:2.1
 ---> a05cc7ed3f32
Step 2 : RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install analysis-phonetic
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ec07bbdb8a18
Successfully built ec07bbdb8a18
Building search
Step 1 : FROM php:5.5.28-fpm
 ---> fcd24d1058c0
...
```

Even when rebuilding using cache, this takes time. So my question is:

Is there a way to **rebuild only one specific container?**

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Yes, use the name of the service:

```
docker-compose build elasticsearch
```

Comment: Use `docker-compose build --no-cache elasticsearch` to force a rebuild of an existing image

Answer (score 61):

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```

[Source](https://staxmanade.com/2016/09/how-to-update-a-single-running-docker-compose-container/)

Comment: why you use -no-deps?

Answer (score 47):

if you want to **run** and **recreate** a specific service inside your docker-compose file you can do it the same way as @dnephin proposed, like

```
$ docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps --build service_name
```

Suppose your docker-compose.yml file is like

```
version: '3'
services:
  service_1:
      .....
  service_2:
      .....
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, if it depends on something it would run everything it depends on.

Comment: Indeed question was about recreating that, i've updated the answer @MariusVanNieuwenhuyse

Comment: why you use force-recreate? is it recreating all or only that building service?

Comment: I had to use `--build` (with `--force-recreate`), even though I had previously, separately, done `docker-compose build service_name`. Otherwise it would just use my existing container.

Answer (score 3):

You could added `--no-start` flag to docker-compose, and start later since you will only build one service.