# How to access MongoDB from PyMongo when using separate docker-compose yaml's?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker-compose, pymongo, bridge

I have **two separate Docker containers, and separate docker-compose YAML's**, too. One ('mongodb') for running the MongoDB, the other ('logger') for data scraping in Python. The latter should write some results into MongoDB.

I used separate yaml's to be able to stop easily one container while not stopping the other one.

To resolve this task I used docker-compose' **bridge network** capability. So I used the following two yaml's:

```
networks:
  wnet:
    driver: bridge

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0.9
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    logging: *default-logging
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - wnet

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
    name: mongodb-data
```

and

```
networks:
  wnet:
    driver: bridge

services:
  logger:
    build:
      context: .
    image:logger:$VERSION
    container_name:logger
    environment:
      - TARGET=$TARGET
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - wnet
```

The Python container should now persist the scraped data within the MongoDB database. So I tried the following variants:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(port=27018, host='mongodb')  # V1
client = MongoClient(port=27018)  # V2
db = client['dbname']
```

Then, executing one of the following commands throws the error:

```
db.list_collection_names()
db.get_collection('aaa').insert_one({ 'a':1 })
```

The response I get is

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb:27018: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Your hostname does not resolve, maybe  you still need to configure something for that.

Comment: @D.SM - okay - but what is the 'something' to configure, and how?

Comment: Now I went into the container and tested it manually. The error is thrown during the insert(), and not before. I will add the information to the post above.

Comment: https://kerneltalks.com/networking/how-docker-container-dns-works/ explains how it works, I don't use docker so don't know what exact steps you need to do.

Comment: Ok, now I found a solution, but not a nice one. In the 'logger' YAML the network is now defined with option external: true. Plus, the MongoDB is accessed from PyMongo by port 27017, not 27018.

Comment: If you are using docker compose then you should really have one compose file with both services; no need to create a network it does that for you; just reference by service name

Comment: @BellyBuster - okay - I will move into that direction. On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466428/how-to-restart-a-single-container-with-docker-compose I found details on how to start and stop single containers. Thx

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked is to refer to the network (defined in container `mongodb`) by its composed name (`mongodb + wnet` = `mongodb_wnet`), and to add the `external` option. This makes the YAML file of the `logger` container look like:

```
services:
  logger:
    build:
      context: .
    image: logger:$VERSION
    container_name: logger
    environment:
      - TARGET=$TARGET
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - mongodb_wnet

networks:
  mongodb_wnet:
    external: true
```

However, as mentioned by @BellyBuster, it might be a **good idea to use one single docker-compose file**. I was not aware that it is quite **easy to start, stop, and build single containers** belonging to the same YAML.

SO has also enough posts on that, e.g. [How to restart a single container with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466428/how-to-restart-a-single-container-with-docker-compose) and/or [docker compose build single container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228970/docker-compose-build-single-container).